# Using python to collect user information from Instagram

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, instagram, screen-scraping

I am currently using python to collect information from users on instagram, using a text file containing the links of the instagram users. While I can collect the # of followers, # following, and # of posts, I want to be able to collect the bio information from the user. Collecting the bio information will allow me to eventually parse through that information and collect emails. What is the best and simplest way I can do this?

I am not as experienced in Python so I took a sample code from the internet. I tried to analyse the code and use what I know to modify it to my needs but with no results.

```py
import requests
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
import json


class Insta_Info_Scraper:

    def getinfo(self, url):
        html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=self.ctx).read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        data = soup.find_all('meta', attrs= {'property':'og:description'})
        text = data[0].get('content').split()
        user = '%s %s %s' % (text[-3], text[-2], text[-1])
        followers = text[0]
        following = text[2]
        posts = text[4]
        email = ""
        print ('User:', user)
        print ('Followers:', followers)
        print ('Following:', following)
        print ('Posts:', posts)
        print ('Email:', email)
        print ('---------------------------')

    def main(self):
        self.ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
        self.ctx.check_hostname = False
        self.ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

        with open('users.txt') as f:
            self.content = f.readlines()
        self.content = [x.strip() for x in self.content]
        for url in self.content:
            self.getinfo(url)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = Insta_Info_Scraper()
    obj.main()
```

At the moment, I put an empty string as the value for the 'email' variable but want to eventually replace it with code that will get the email from the specific users.

Comment: Hello @rivas142. It's good that you included and formatted the code. You should also take a look here for more information about formatting: [format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: it's work but not all post get only last 12 posts get, so how to get all post

Answer (score 3):

A handy tool for accessing Instagram's public data structures is [Instaloader](https://instaloader.github.io/), a Python package that provides both a Python module and a CLI to access Instagram. After doing a `pip install instaloader` to install it, you can easily get the Profile's metadata saved in JSON files with

```
instaloader --no-posts --no-profile-pic --no-compress-json profile1 [profile2 ...]
```

Then you can use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), "a lightweight and flexible command-line JSON processor", to extract just-saved information, e.g. the following command prints the biography of profile1:

```
jq -r .node.biography profile1/profile1_*.json
```

Likewise, a way not leaving Python to access the same information:

```
import instaloader
L = instaloader.Instaloader()
profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(L.context, 'profile1')
print(profile.biography)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is using third party libraries like [instagram_private_api](https://instagram-private-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

example:

```
from instagram_web_api import Client

web_api = Client(auto_patch=True, drop_incompat_keys=False)
user_info = web_api.user_info2('instagram')
print(user_info)
```